# Excel calculate the duration between two weekdays time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Calculate the duration between file release and completed time]

Hi,

I have this table with me, each record represents one file. My objective is to calculate out the duration for the file to complete.

I stuck at some files are completed within the same day, while some files might complete only after 1 or 2 or 3 days.

Are there any formulas to calculate it out?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the `Mon`,`Tue`,`Wed`,... text or dates that are formatted `ddd`?

Comment: If file completion takes more than one day, do you need to calculate full time (1 full day = 24hrs) or work time (1 full day = 8 hrs or whatever your office hours are). What about files that span a weekend?

Comment: @ScottCraner Those are text

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad need to calculate full time. weekend doesn't count .

Comment: So what if the task takes longer than a week, how is excel supposed to know?

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the reminder! The duration should within a week only.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off with a single date and time column then use something like the below. Otherwise combine the date and time yourself first

```
=(TIMEVALUE(B2)-TIMEVALUE(C2)+(TIMEVALUE(B2)<TIMEVALUE(C2)))*24
```

Comment: @The weekdays is text format, not date format. I cannot combine them with time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to achieve that. [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QvMW.png)

First I would apologize for my unclear question. The weekdays are text format, the weekend doesn't count, and the durations are confirmed within one week period.

I actually did the below steps and achieved to my objective.

1. Convert all the weekdays to numbers, refer to column J and K.
2. Column L is the variance between column J and K. L=K-J
3. Then the duration M column put this formula will do.

   =IF(L2=0,MOD(I2-G2,1)*24,IF(AND(L2=1,I2>=G2),MOD(I2-G2,1)*24+L2*24,IF(AND(L2=2,I2>=G2),MOD(I2-G2,1)*24+L2*24,IF(AND(L2=3,I2>=G2),MOD(I2-G2,1)*24+L2*24,MOD(I2-G2,1)*24+(L2-1)*24))))